# How to run a PWA program made with Python and flet on the Internet

Tags: python, progressive-web-apps, replit, flet, fly

I have created an application using flet and now I want to upload it as a PWA so that anyone can access it and I also want to assign a domain to it.
First of all, how do I do this? (I don't intend to use fly.io for some reason)
And can I get a server and run it on the server? How?

I used fly.io but it asked me to enter a credit card which I don't have available at the moment.
I also used replit, but when I tried to replace the existing program with my own program, it gave many errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Buy a **domain main**. You can use domain register such as [Porkbun](https://porkbun.com/) or [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/). Basic .com domain cost around 10$/year. I recommend you buy domain name like ***firstnamelastname.com*** or ***lastname.com*** and host your services at subdomains like myapp.mydomain.com. And you actually need credit card here.
2. Get a server. I personally using [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.com/) VPS servers. Cheapest one cost something like 3.5 euros/month. If you dont have credit card, you can look at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). There is free plan available and if you didnt buy a domain name you can use their domain. For example, an app named `example-app` is hosted at `example-app-1234567890ab.herokuapp.com`. But free plan is very restricted.
3. If you bought custom domain then you should configure your **DNS records** to point to your server.
4. Deploy the app. If you use VPS you should know basics of linux, also git for copy your project to the server. For heroku read [their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).
5. If you use VPS you also want to use reverse proxy like Nginx or Caddy or Traefik to point local address to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, `fly.io` has a free/trial tier (I currently use it). If you don't have a credit card, maybe self hosting would be a better option.